# Request for delete takes too much time

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, time

I have an application where I have a page to display the records in a gridview but it has more than 1000 of records.

Now for "Delete" a record, I have used TemplateField as below:

```
<asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-CssClass="DeleteItem">
    <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" Text="Delete" CommandName="Delete"
            CausesValidation="false" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure want to Delete')">
        </asp:LinkButton>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:TemplateField>
```

And in code behind, I just delete it from the database as below:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDeleting(object sender, GridViewDeleteEventArgs e)
{
    // Here I just delete it from the database
}
```

But now the issue comes when on a live application when I click on a delete then it takes around more than 1 minute to delete it from the database.

I also checked firebug to see the request time. so it first make a `Post (302)` request which takes too much time. And this only happens on a live site.

Can anyone tell me why it happens so and the solution for it.?

[image: 302 Response]

Comment: Can you add the code you use to delete from db?

Comment: It doesn't matter because the time only taken before the control comes to that place so time taken only while Posting the page..

Comment: only i can suggest is remove use of rowdeleting command, use linkbutton onclick and pass primarykey as commandargument, and you can take commandargument withing linkbutton click event from sender object. also reduce using rowdatabound if you have used. this is too old technique of having gridview on your asp.net, try to use repeater and custom paging because once you delete record you will add databind for grid that will again bind your data, tooks time to load 1000s of records.

Comment: Have you performed any diagnostics to work out *where* the time is going? Is it the database?

Comment: @JonSkeet On my local PC when I work with the same database then it works just fine without any delay..so here the time only be taken while `Post 302` request. If I use linkbutton and redirect to some other page then it works fine.

Comment: That hasn't answered my question about diagnostics at all. It's not really clear what you mean by a "Post (302)" request in the first place. Do you mean it's a POST request which gets a 302 response? You also haven't told us what that POST request you've observed contains. Basically there's a *lot* of diagnostic information missing here.

Comment: @JonSkeet Yes, it is a POST request which gets a 302 response..you can see in the image above..

Comment: @VishalSuthar: And presumably that POST is the one which contains the delete call to the database, right?

Comment: Yes, that is the case.. I guess because the page contains huge data around 1000 records in a gridview so the entire page is POSTed on a server as I can also see "Uploading ...%" on a browser..

Comment: I second Jon Skeet. Profile your issue. You are making assumptions about something you probably do not know well, as typically does everyone else, too. Profile it to see your hotspot